# Enum as Flag using, setting and shifting

Tags: c#, .net, enums, flags

I have two flags:

```
[Flags]
enum Flags
{
  A = 1,
  B = 2
};
```

I set them like this:

```
Mode = Flags.A | Flags.B; // default value
for(int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++) {
switch(args[i])
{
  case "--a":
  {
    if ((Mode & Flags.A) == Flags.A && (Mode & Flags.B) == Flags.B) 
     // both, default assume
    {
      Mode = Flags.A; // only A
    }
    else
    {
      Mode |= Flags.A; // append A
    }
    break;
  }
  case "--b":
  {
    if ((Mode & Flags.A) == Flags.A && (Mode & Flags.B) == Mode.B)
    {
      Mode = Flags.B;
    }
    else
    {
      Mode |= Flags.B;
    }
    break;
  }
} }
```

and use them later like this:

```
if((Mode & Flags.A) == Flags.A)
{
 //
}
if((Mode & Flags.B) == Flags.B)
{
 //
}
```

Major reservation: Both flags may be set. Or just one, in this case only one part of code is executed.

Is my code good? What is the best way to setup flags?

**Upd**:
Is this less ugly then first, how do you think?

```
Mode = 0; // default value now is empty
for(int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++) {
switch(args[i])
{
  case "--a":
  {
    Mode |= Flags.A;
    break;
  }
  case "--b":
  {
    Mode |= Flags.B;
    break;
  }
} }
if(Mode == 0)
{
  Mode = Flags.A | Flags.B; // if no parameters are given, setup both flags
}
```

Comment: Your code is syntactically correct but its hard to say whether it's "good" without understanding your problem a bit more. Your question is a bit vague and your comments on answers make it more so.  Can you give a bit more? On the face of it your solution is too complex for the problem as presented.

Comment: Hi. There is default value A|B. If parameter --a is given set mode only to A, if --b only to B, and if both are given to (as default) A|B. What is the best way to check is current value is default (A|B) to change it to A or B if required.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how I would set my flags:

```
Mode = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++) {
    switch(args[i]) {
    case "--a":
        Mode |= Flags.A;
        break;
    case "--b":
        Mode |= Flags.B;
        break;
    }
}
```

If both flags should be on by default, I think it makes more sense to change the command line parameters to something like `--not-a` and `--not-b`. This would both reflect the default setting, and let you get rid of `(Mode & Flags.A) == Flags.A && (Mode & Flags.B) == Flags.B`, which is rather ugly, IMHO.

Then you can set your flags like this:

```
Mode = Flags.A | Flags.B;
for(int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++) {
    switch(args[i]) {
    case "--not-a":
        Mode &= ~Flags.A;
        break;
    case "--not-b":
        Mode &= ~Flags.B;
        break;
    }
}
```

Finally, if you have a lot of flags (instead of just two), it might be easier to set up your enum like this:

```
[Flags]
enum Flags
{
    A = 1,
    B = 1 << 1,
    C = 1 << 2,
    D = 1 << 3,
    E = 1 << 4,
    F = 1 << 5
};
```

Comment: Main remark is about default value is A | B. So just appending using |= is not enough.

Comment: I agree about ugliness of that code, look please at head post, what do you think?

Comment: The new code is much better, but I still think --not-a and --not-b make more sense. On the other hand, Mode will never be null (you set it to 0), so you should check for Mode == 0.

Answer (score 2):

You can turn a "bit" off with the following wonderful statement:

```
Mode &= ~Flags.A;
```

I'd reccoment including a "null" value in your enum as well:

```
[Flags]
enum Flags
{
  Null = 0;
  A = 1,
  B = 2;
}
```

It will keep your life simpler! :-)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at &=~ !
But disagree with you about having null-flag. MSDN recommends do not! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229062.aspx "There is no way to check for a zero value flag being explicitly set, as opposed to no flags being set."

Comment: It is not for setting any individual bit. It is for clearing and giving a defined default value. And it is easier to test if a bit is set by typing if ( (Mode & Flags.A) != Flags.Null. There are many reasons why yo're life will be simpler with a .Null value. Trust me on this one!

Comment: I agree with having a zero value for a flags-style enum, but Microsoft recommends the name None, not Null - as mentioned in the document @abatishchev links to.

Answer (score 1):

The second version is much better - this is exactly what I would do. Change `Mode == null` to `Mode == 0` though.

```
Mode = 0; // default value now is empty
for(int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++) {
    switch(args[i])
    {
        case "--a":
            Mode |= Flags.A;
            break;

        case "--b":
            Mode |= Flags.B;
            break;
    }
}

if(Mode == 0)
{
    Mode = Flags.A | Flags.B; // if no parameters are given, setup both flags
}
```