# How to convert bitmasked values to an options object?

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, bitmask

I have to read/write an XML file that stores its data as bit masked values.

e.g.

```
<panel>
    <options arming="21" opt_b="51" opt_c="6" />
</panel>
```

in this case, `arming` has the value `21`, but this corresponds to the following string of bytes:

```
10101
```

and those bytes correspond to options 0,2,4 in the following list:

- **Bit 0: Forced arm**
- Bit 1: Final door
- **Bit 2: Exit fault**
- Bit 3: Inhibit tamper
- **Bit 4: Display**
- Bit 8: Rearm
- Bit 9: Line
- Bit 10: Extend block

What's the best way for me to

- convert this from the decimal value of `21` to an object model that represents the options?
- use that object to display these as options for the user to select and deselect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare an enum thus:

```
[Flags]
public enum ArmingFlags {
   None=0
   Forced_arm = 1
   Final_door = 2
   Exit_fault = 4
   Inhibit_tamper = 8
   Display = 16
   Rearm = 32
   Line = 64
   Extend_block = 128
}
```

Note my use of powers of two in the enum.  These allow an enum to represent discrete values using binary bit positions (see [Why do enum permissions often have 0, 1, 2, 4 values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811114/why-do-enum-permissions-often-have-0-1-2-4-values/9811145#9811145))

then parse your value into an integer and cast that to a type of ArmingFlags (note, untested code ahead but should work):

```
ArmingFlags flagsVal = ArmingFlags.None;
Int32 val;
if (Int32.TryParse(armingString, out val)) {
    flagsVal = (ArmingFlags)val;
}

// Then you can test it for expected values:
if ((flagsVal & ArmingFlags.Rearm) == ArmingFlags.Rearm) {
    //The Rearm bit was set...
}
```

There are lots of posts on how to use an enum in a WPF combobox or radio buttons, for instance:

[Databinding an enum property to a ComboBox in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58743/databinding-an-enum-property-to-a-combobox-in-wpf)

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Note - I've edited the answer to add some brackets. Just wondering though, why write `((flagsVal & ArmingFlags.Rearm) == ArmingFlags.Rearm)`? Wouldn't `(flagsVal == ArmingFlags.Rearm)` work just the same? It seems redundant, but I've seen a couple of other examples like that. It worked when I tested it with both examples though.

Comment: You want to test for a single flag amongst (potentially) multiple flags.  For instance, the value you showed in the OP (10101) is not equal to ArmingFlags.Forced_arm (it is `ArmingFlags.Forced_arm & ArmingFlags.Exit_fault & ArmingFlags.Display`).  To test the specific flag bit you need to filter out all of the other 1's in the value and then perform the equality test.

Comment: Really it is best explained in the post I linked above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811114/why-do-enum-permissions-often-have-0-1-2-4-values/9811145#9811145

Answer (score 2):

How about using the power of enums to help you along your way:

```
[Flags]
public enum AlarmData
{
    ForcedArm = 1,
    FinalDoor = 2,
    ExitFault = 4,
    InhibitTamper = 8,
    Display = 16,
    Rearm = 32,
    Line = 64,
    ExtendBlock = 128
}

private static Dictionary<AlarmData, string> alarmDataLookup = new Dictionary<AlarmData, string>
{
    { AlarmData.ForcedArm, "Forced arm" },
    { AlarmData.FinalDoor, "Final door" },
    { AlarmData.ExitFault, "Exit fault" },
    { AlarmData.InhibitTamper , "Inhibit tamper" },
    { AlarmData.Display , "Display" },
    { AlarmData.Rearm , "Rearm" },
    { AlarmData.Line , "Line" },
    { AlarmData.ExtendBlock , "Extend block" }
};

public IEnumerable<string> EnumerateValues(AlarmData data)
{
    return from pair in alarmDataLookup 
            where data.HasFlag(pair.Key) 
            select pair.Value;
}
```

Calling the EnumerateValues is simple once you've read out the value from the XML, just cast the integer as the AlarmData enum, e.g.:

```
int value = GetAlarmValueFromXml();
var bindableValues = EnumerateValues((AlarmData)value);
```

Of course, you don't have to return strings from the EnumerateValues method. All you would then need to do is bind the result of the method to a list or some other element, and Bob's your uncle.