# Best way to 'remap' a simple binary mask?

Tags: c#, binary, remap

I got a very simple binary mask.

> 1 = Sunday
>
> 2 = Saturday
>
> **4** = Friday
>
> **8** = Thursday
>
> **16** = Wednesday
>
> 32 = Tuesday
>
> 64 = Monday
>
> So if you want a combination of Wednesday, Thursday and Friday you get **16 + 8 + 4 = 28**

Now further along my code I only have the mapped binary value. What would be the best way to 'remap' this value (28) to Wed, Thu and Fri?

Hope to get some input on how to do this :).

Kind regards,
Niels

Comment: What do you mean by 'remap'? Is it simply an issue of having lost the enum type, or is it an issue of getting a readable string description of the value?

Comment: here is a good solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261451/using-a-bitmask-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use an enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum WeekDays
{
    Sunday = 1,
    Saturday = 2,
    Friday = 4,
    Thursday = 8,
    Wednesday = 16,
    Tuesday = 32,
    Monday = 64
}
```

A simple explicit conversion will do the "remapping" you're interested in:

```
WeekDays days = (WeekDays) 28;
```

You can easily use normal bitwise operations:

```
if ((days & WeekDays.Friday) != 0)
{
    // Yes, the mask included Friday
}
```

And you could do that in a loop:

```
foreach (WeekDays day in Enum.GetValues(typeof(WeekDays))
{
    if ((days & day) != 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Got {0}", day);
    }
}
```

Even just using `Console.WriteLine(days)` will give you a comma-separated representation.

You may also find the utility methods in my [Unconstrained Melody](https://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/) library useful (in particular the [`Flags`](https://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/source/browse/trunk/UnconstrainedMelody/Flags.cs) code).

If you're looking for something else, please be more specific.

Comment: Could you include some sample code of how to use those Utility methods to produce the answer the OP is looking for? That'd be especially helpful.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: It's not entirely clear exactly what the OP *does* want, to be honest - one variable? Three?

Comment: Also, `ToString()` on a `Flags` `enum` can produce "Wednesday, Thursday, Friday".

Comment: @CoryNelson: Yup - "Even just using `Console.WriteLine(days)` will give you a comma-separated representation." (Although I don't know what the ordering would be.)

Comment: Yes, I would like to get all variables :). Thanks!

Comment: @Niels: Well then see the loop that I've given near the end of the answer.

Comment: I really think hex (or bitshifting) is cleaner than decimal for representing flags ([like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13222740/18192)).

Comment: @Brian: I was just copying that aspect from the original question. They're semantically identical, of course. The important part of the answer is how to *use* those values.