# How to check is string match one of the regex in array?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string, laravel

I want to create something like permissions in my project. 
How do I check is string match one of the regex in array?

```php
//Array of user (group) permissions.
$arrayOfPermissions = [
    'admin.users.edit',
    'admin.users.*',
    'dashboard.view',

];

//Check is this permission presents in array
$stringToMatch = 'admin.users.view';
```

`*` sign mean that user have all permissions in this group.

For exemple:

If user have permission `admin.users.*` so he should pass validation for `admin.users.view`

**UPD:**
I use this now, but it looks like this is not good.

```php
private function checkPerms($permission)
{
    $arrayOfPermissions = [
        'admin.dashboard.view',
        'admin.users.*'

    ];

    foreach ($arrayOfPermissions as $perm)
    {
        if(preg_match("/".$perm."/", $permission))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

//This should return `true`
checkPerms("admin.users.view");
```

P.S. I use Laravel.

Comment: Array values are not regexes.

Comment: Why not just `admin.users` ?

Comment: @splash58 because if user have permission like `admin.users.*` he should can do any staff where required `admin.users.edit` or `admin.users.create` etc.

Comment: @u_mulder `*` sign is regex

Comment: Maybe [this different permissions concept would be interesting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811114/why-do-enum-permissions-often-have-0-1-2-4-values).

Comment: This isn't an answer, but note that in regexes, `.` is a special character, and `*` doesn't mean the same thing it means in a wildcard match, typeglob, etc. If you want a regex to match a literal `.`, use `\.`. If you want a typeglob-style `*`, use `.+` (or `.*` if you want the empty string to be a valid match). For example, instead of `'admin.users.*'`, use `'admin\\.users\\..+'`. The string you've used as a regex will match the strings you want to match, but also others such as `admin-userstrike`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the array of permissions include permissions ending with a wildcard (`*`) or ones with full names.

Iterate through the permissions,

- If they contain a wildcard (`*`), check if the permission to be checked starts with it
- Else the permission should be completely matched

Code:

```
echo hasPermission($arrayOfPermissions, $stringToMatch) ? "Has Access" : "Access Denied";

function hasPermission($arrayOfPermissions, $stringToMatch) 
    // Iterate through all permissions
    foreach ($arrayOfPermissions as $permission) {
        // Check if permission contains a wildcard
        if(strpos($permission, '.*')) {
            $prefix = substr($permission, 0, strpos($permission, '.*'));
            if(startsWith($stringToMatch, $prefix))
                return true;
        // Else, match completely
        } else {
            if($permission == $stringToMatch)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function startsWith($string, $test)
{
    $length = strlen($test);
    return (substr($string, 0, $length) === $test);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check by in_array() or you imploding the values and the regex would like this: /(permission1|permisson2..)/

Answer (score -1):

I guess here is what you could do:

- Remove the .* from the string, if any.
- In a foreach loop through permission check if string starts with manipulated string from above

No regex needed.